# how to use `helm add | search` agains oci:// repos

Tags: kubernetes-helm, karpenter

For example:

```
➜ helm repo add karpenter oci://public.ecr.aws/karpenter/karpenter                                 
Error: looks like "oci://public.ecr.aws/karpenter/karpenter" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: object required
```

as the karpenter's  https://charts.karpenter.sh  has only old versions

I want to be able to search for repo and see values

i.e.
`helm show values karpenter/karpenter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across the same issue.
Reading https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/ helped me.
As far as I understand it works without `helm repo add`.

You could try:

```bash
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws
helm show values oci://public.ecr.aws/karpenter/karpenter --version v0.29.0
```